# Software for computation of Ricci tensor on a Kähler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, math-software, kahler-manifolds

I have a metric on a Kähler manifold and want to compute the Ricci tensor. There are packages for Mathematica to do this on a real manifold, but I have not found any software to do explicit calculations with say complex differential forms.